# Having trouble get the right output from a MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database that includes the following tables:

- User
- Category
- Article

Inside our website we have a section called "editors pick" that has 5 of the best articles chosen by editors on that area.

Editors must set "is_recommended = yes" and also "recommended_location" which can be either 1,2,3,4, or 5; accordingly they will be placed on one of those 1-5 placements on the website.

Articles also have a "start_date" meaning the author can write an article assign it as is_recommended = yes and recommended_location = 3 and then set it for tomorrow 9pm. Therefore the article will only appear tomorrow and when it does it should sit on the 3 box of the editors pick.

Sometimes we may have an article such as below:

- ID: 123
- is_recommended: yes
- recommended_location = 3
- start_date = 06-05-2016 09:00:00 (let's say this is yesterday)

Which is currently holding the #3 spot.

I have another article:

- ID: 456
- is_recommended: yes
- recommended_location = 3
- start_date = 07-05-2016 09:00:00 (this is today and today it is already 11am)

However my query still continues to show ID: 123; while I want it to show the one in slot #3 that is the newest (meaning 456)

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong in my query below, how can I assure that for each slot the newest item is selected?

This is the query:

```
select * 
from (
    select article.*, user.username, category.title as ctitle, user.firstname, user.lastname, category.slug as cslug, category.category_id as pid 
    from article 
    left join user on article.created_by = user.id 
    left join category on category.id = article.category_id 
    where article.status='active' 
    AND is_recommended='yes' 
    AND article.start_date<='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."' 
    AND recommended_location in (1,2,3,4,5) 
    order by start_date desc
 ) as x 
 group by recommended_location 
 limit 5
```

Comment: you should have an end_date comparison as well even if it meant manually adding 1 day to start_date. that way you can use something like date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date...so there's no confusion between what rows should be returned.

Comment: @Turo has the solution you want. It's a non-trivial problem you are trying to solve. Read [this article](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) about trying to solve this type of problem

Comment: Thanks @AgRizzo this is exactly the problem. Now to put 2+2 together.

Comment: @TinTran but it does not make sense for our system, end dates are unclear and actually non-existant. Once an article is live it needs to stay live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You havent't aggregation function so you don't need group by  (eventually use distinct if this is what you need)

```
select * 
from (    select article.*, user.username, category.title as ctitle, user.firstname, user.lastname, category.slug as cslug, category.category_id as pid 
    from article 
    left join user on article.created_by = user.id 
    left join category on category.id = article.category_id 
    where article.status='active' 
    AND is_recommended='yes' 
    AND article.start_date<='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."' 
    AND recommended_location in (1,2,3,4,5) 
    order by start_date desc
 ) as x 
 limit 5
```

If you want only a article for each recommended_location you should use

```
(select article.*, user.username, category.title as ctitle, user.firstname, user.lastname, category.slug as cslug, category.category_id as pid 
from article 
left join user on article.created_by = user.id 
left join category on category.id = article.category_id 
where article.status='active' 
AND is_recommended='yes' 
AND article.start_date<='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."' 
AND recommended_location = '1' 
order by start_date desc limit 1)
union
(select article.*, user.username, category.title as ctitle, user.firstname, user.lastname, category.slug as cslug, category.category_id as pid 
from article 
left join user on article.created_by = user.id 
left join category on category.id = article.category_id 
where article.status='active' 
AND is_recommended='yes' 
AND article.start_date<='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."' 
AND recommended_location = '2' 
order by start_date desc limit 1)
union 
(select article.*, user.username, category.title as ctitle, user.firstname, user.lastname, category.slug as cslug, category.category_id as pid 
from article 
left join user on article.created_by = user.id 
left join category on category.id = article.category_id 
where article.status='active' 
AND is_recommended='yes' 
AND article.start_date<='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."' 
AND recommended_location = '3' 
order by start_date desc limit 1)   
union 
(select article.*, user.username, category.title as ctitle, user.firstname, user.lastname, category.slug as cslug, category.category_id as pid 
from article 
left join user on article.created_by = user.id 
left join category on category.id = article.category_id 
where article.status='active' 
AND is_recommended='yes' 
AND article.start_date<='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."' 
AND recommended_location = '4' 
order by start_date desc limit 1)  
union 
(select article.*, user.username, category.title as ctitle, user.firstname, user.lastname, category.slug as cslug, category.category_id as pid 
from article 
left join user on article.created_by = user.id 
left join category on category.id = article.category_id 
where article.status='active' 
AND is_recommended='yes' 
AND article.start_date<='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."' 
AND recommended_location = '5' 
order by start_date desc limit 1)
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this is not generating the right results.
I need to get the latest item per recommended_location; however this query is getting them and placing them randomly; I now have two items in the 1-5 that are set as recommended_location = 3

Comment: I have yet to check if this works but won't this be a massive load on server? We have over 100K users on the site and I am trying to find ways to optimize. I understand we can cache but generally a query this long is quite scary to say the least.

Comment: It is working ... I am contemplating if it is the right way to go ahead or not.

Comment: well if this answer working is a good result   .. then i think this is at  least useful ..  I think in that case (one element for each category ) .. the select union with limit is the simple (or the unique)  solution..

Comment: I appreciate your help on this. It saves us for a short period while we find the long period answer.

Comment: Well I'm my experience  .. i think the solution provided . is the more simple .. could be not the unique .. but concettualy  easy and poweful.. anyway . if answer id right .and coherent with the question . is fair flag as accepted too..

Answer (score 1):

Make the aggregation first and then join the data you need

```
select x.recommended_location, x.start_date, ... 
from
 ( select article.recommended_location, max(article.start_date) as  start_date 
    from article 
     where article.status='active' 
     AND is_recommended='yes' 
     AND article.start_date<='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."' 
    AND recommended_location in (1,2,3,4,5) 
    group by article.recommended_location
 ) as x 
inner join article on x.recommended_location = artice.recommended_location    
and x.start_date = article.start_date
inner join ...
```

But if 2 or more articles have the same start_date, you will get all of them this way...

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Use article.id with descending order in query

so your query is like this :

```
select * 
from (
    select article.*, user.username, category.title as ctitle, user.firstname, user.lastname, category.slug as cslug, category.category_id as pid 
    from article 
    left join user on article.created_by = user.id 
    left join category on category.id = article.category_id 
    where article.status='active' 
    AND is_recommended='yes' 
    AND article.start_date<='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."' 
    AND recommended_location in (1,2,3,4,5) 
    order by article.ID desc, recommended_location desc, start_date desc
 ) as x 
 group by recommended_location 
 limit 5
```

I hope you will get solution.

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately it is not giving me the result I am looking for.